# Choice Field Options Limit

Tags: servicenow

`What is the maximum number of options than can be added to a choice type field in servicenow CRM?`

Is there any default maximum count limit is available, for options that can be added? Or 
Can we set the maximum count of options somewhere in CRM?

Comment: Got response from servicenow Community.Please refer https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=d79fb6bbdb6044105ed4a851ca961980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got response from servicenow Community.Please refer link

https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=d79fb6bbdb6044105ed4a851ca961980